# Calculating a percentage column

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to create a percentage column in SSRS, shown below.  So the calculation would be 989 / 2231 * 100 = 44%  Would appreciate some help please.

```
Country     Total     Percentage
UK           989          44% 
France       567          25%
Belgium      675          30%
GrandTotal   2231
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
=Sum(Fields!Total.Value)/Sum(Fields!Total.Value,"DataSetName")
```

Replace DataSetName by the actual name of your dataset. Also you don't have to explicetely multiply by 100, you can format the cell to show the result in percentage format instead.

Or you can format the value from the expression:

```
=FORMAT(Sum(Fields!Total.Value)/Sum(Fields!Total.Value,"DataSetName"),"P0")
```

**UPDATE:** Explanation about FORMAT function.

Format function takes two arguments. The first argument is the value you can format, it can be dates, numbers, percentages, etc. The second argument is a string that represents the format you want to apply. In this case my format is "P0" where `P` stands for Percentage and `0` is the number of decimals you want the percentage include, zero as your requeriment.

[REFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, this is what i get.....The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox10.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30451] Name 'Total' is not declared.

Comment: @whitz11, What is the name of the field you want to sum?

Comment: The Format way has worked, thank you so much.  Do you mind just explaining what that does as I don't fully understand?

Comment: @whitz11, I've updated my answer adding a short explanation about format works.